# Logstash unable to load, file not readable

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, logstash

Trying to sync between MongoDB and Elasticsearch with [MongoDbJdbcDriver](https://dbschema.com/jdbc-drivers/MongoDbJdbcDriver.zip) by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58849340/10583765). I use `docker-compose` for development, and this is how it looks like for `logstash`:

```yaml
  logstash:
    image: logstash:7.9.1
    container_name: logstash
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/jars/gson-2.8.6.jar:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/gson-2.8.6.jar:ro
      - ./logstash/jars/mongojdbc2.3.jar:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mongojdbc2.3.jar:ro
      - ./logstash/jars/mongo-java-driver-3.12.6.jar:/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mongo-java-driver-3.12.6.jar:ro
      - ./logstash/config/pipelines.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
      - ./logstash/pipeline/mongo-to-elasticsearch.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/mongo-to-elasticsearch.conf
    command: logstash
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

I run `docker-compose up` and it gives this error:

```
...
logstash         |   Error: unable to load mongojdbc2.3.jar from :jdbc_driver_library, file not readable (please check user and group permissions for the path)
logstash         |   Exception: LogStash::PluginLoadingError
...
```

I've checked file permission of `mongojdbc2.3.jar` on my machine, given read and write for me and docker group. However when I check inside `logstash` container, owner is not `root` but `logstash`:

```
// ls -l /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars

...
-rw-r--r-- 1 logstash logstash  2315317 Jul 24 15:13 mongo-java-driver-3.12.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 logstash logstash    83500 Sep  8 01:30 mongojdbc2.3.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 logstash root       107210 Sep  1 23:32 org.eclipse.core.commands-3.6.0.jar
...
```

I tried changing ownership inside container but I couldn't do it since I don't have the `sudo` permission.

Please help, how I can I sync between MongoDB and Elasticsearch successfully?

---

Stack: MongoDB (v4.4.1), Logstash (v7.9.1), Docker (v19.03.12), Docker-compose (v1.27.3)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new image with jars in it

```
  logstash:
    build: ./logstash/
    container_name: logstash
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/pipelines.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
      - ./logstash/pipeline/mongo-to-elasticsearch.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/mongo-to-elasticsearch.conf
    command: logstash
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

`./logstash/Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.1

COPY ./jars/ /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars
```